# NOT EXISTS Vs. Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, not-exists

I am confused by the results that I am getting via the `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with NULL.

Consider the below 2 queries which produce very different results. Please note that the `fkMasterPersonID` is NOT a foreign key to the right table (`tblInternetMasterPerson`)

**Query 1**

```
SELECT tl.pkLeadID, tl.fkMasterPersonID
FROM dbo.tblPhoneLead tl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT MasterPersonID
    FROM dbo.tblInternetMasterPerson
)
```

The above returns no results

**Query 2**

```
SELECT tl.pkLeadID, tl.fkMasterPersonID
FROM dbo.tblPhoneLead tl
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblInternetMasterPerson mp
    ON tl.fkMasterPersonID = mp.MasterPersonID
WHERE tl.fkMasterPersonID IS null
```

The above returns 237 records where the `fkMasterPersonID` are all NULL.

What would be the correct way of determining through `NOT EXISTS` whether the `fkMasterPersonID` DOES NOT exist on the `dbo.tblInternetMasterPerson`? This table does have the column `pkMasterPersonID` but it is auto incremented and is not a foreign key to any other table.

Comment: Your not exists query is flawed because you don't correlate it to your main query. It should be `WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT MasterPersonID FROM dbo.tblInternetMasterPerson mp where tl.fkMasterPersonID = mp.MasterPersonID)`

Comment: Those two queries are not equivalent because the first one will always return something if `tblInternetMasterPerson` contains at least one row.

Comment: Your query is very strange, to test `WHERE tl.fkMasterPersonID IS null` shouldn't require a join at all. You really need to provide some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correlate the exists subquery to the outer query.  Here is one way:

```sql
SELECT tl.pkLeadID, tl.fkMasterPersonID
FROM dbo.tblPhoneLead tl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.tblInternetMasterPerson mp
    WHERE mp.MasterPersonID = tl.fkMasterPersonID
);
```